# How to set QComboBox background color on drop down state?

Tags: c++, qt, background, qcombobox

I can change `QComboBox` color like this:

```
QPalette palette = ui->selectSource->palette();
palette.setColor(QPalette::Active, QPalette::Button, Qt::white);
palette.setColor(QPalette::Inactive, QPalette::Button, Qt::white);
ui->selectSource->setPalette(palette);
```

It becomes white, but when its in drop down state it still have some gray color (default).

How to change this?

Comment: Maybe apply the same palette to combo box's drop down view too? You can get it with `QComboBox::view()` function.

Comment: @vahancho, worked! Good idea.

Comment: @vahancho, it must be "QPalette::Background" for the view. Please, fix your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply one more palette to the combo box's drop down view too. To get the pointer to the drop down view you can use the `QComboBox::view()` function. So, your code will look like:

```
QPalette palette = ui->selectSource->palette();
palette.setColor(QPalette::Active, QPalette::Button, Qt::white);
palette.setColor(QPalette::Inactive, QPalette::Button, Qt::white);

QPalette view_palette = ui->selectSource->view()->palette();
view_palette.setColor(QPalette::Active, QPalette::Background, Qt::white);
ui->selectSource->view()->setPalette(view_palette);
```

Comment: Strange, this code doesn't work for me but Nejat's code does. I am so confused...0rz

Comment: @Tay2510, I'm using Qt v5.3.x. You?

Comment: @AlekDepler Qt 4.8.6 with Windows 7 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

You should also set `QPalette::Base` role. Quote from the Qt documentation about `QPalette::Base` :

> Used mostly as the background color for text entry widgets, but can
>   also be used for other painting - such as the background of combobox
>   drop down lists and toolbar handles. It is usually white or another
>   light color.

So you should also have :

```
palette.setColor(QPalette::Base, Qt::white);
```

Comment: That's weird. It works for me both on Linux and Windows.

Comment: @Tay2510, now that's weird for me, cause "palette.setColor(QPalette::Base, Qt::white);" do nothing in my code. Maybe some other property of my main window is different or I miss something.